# Copy just the data columns from a SQLAlchemy object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an object

```
esc = Escalation.query\
    .filter(Escalation.esc_id == esc_id).first()
```

And I would like to copy all of the columns except the primary key and foreign keys so that I can make a new copy of this object in the database with new relationships.

Currently I just make a constructor that can take a Escalation instance so I can say

```
new_esc = Escalation(esc)
```

but I was wondering if there is a built in feature for SQLAlchemy that solves this problem.
I looked at session.merge but I don't want to take the entire state.

Comment: Take a look at [`make_transient`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.make_transient), and also see similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636192/sqlalchemy-modification-of-detached-object. You still might deal with the foreign keys though.

Answer (score 1):

I think `make_transient` looks like a great solution.  This is not built-in, but I've subclassed `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.DeclarativeMeta` to have a custom `__init__` and gave it some iteration methods, so that you could unpack instance values into a new instance like this:

```
new_esc = Escalation(**esc)
```

It was kind of a pain to do, though.  Metaclasses are fragile and hurt my brain.